# How to fix routing behind off-the-shelf router?

Tags: routing

I have been fighting with a routing problem for a whole evening today, I have finally found what is the symptom, but I have no idea how to fix the problem.

Basically, I have a router that is connected to internet and I have multiple PCs sitting behind it.

- router: `192.168.1.1`
- pc-s:   `192.168.1.0/24` (if this is the correct syntax)

I want to create a LAN party in this subnet. So that `192.168.1.100` could play with `192.168.1.101`.

The problem is, that it doesn't work.

After hours of head scratching, firewall configurations, router configurations and debugging, I finally found the symptom.

I compiled two programs based of MSDN winsock sapmple and launched a server on machine `192.168.1.100`

Then I launched the client (`192.168.1.101`), to connect to server (`192.168.1.100`). There is a silence.

But when I join the two PC's with a patch cable on hand crafted/static IP network `192.168.3.0/24`, alongside the still functional `192.168.1.0/24` network.

So when server is `192.168.3.1` and `192.168.1.100`, and client `192.168.3.2` and `192.168.1.101`, the connection goes through. Both to `192.168.1.100` and to `192.168.3.1`.

I have a Linksys router, and it seems it's swallowing local network traffic. Is there a fix for that?

EDIT:
Route table on router has this:

```
Destination         LAN IP        Subnet Mask       Gateway        Interface
192.168.1.0                       255.255.255.0     0.0.0.0        LAN & Wireless
xxx.xxx.xxx.0                     255.255.252.0     0.0.0.0        WAN (Internet)
0.0.0.0                           0.0.0.0           xxx.xxx.xxx.1  WAN (Internet)
```

Comment: Client/server.. why not just ping ? 
Is it wifi or cables ? For wifi some routers have a setting to disable traffic between local peers. For cables it should have nothing to do with the router - pcs talk directly over lan regardless what router you plug there. Do you use DHCP or you configure ips statically ?

Comment: @Alex: I'm not very good with network stuff, so I decided winsocks cli/srv was safer. I haven't found one so far. Yes, but if I connect the cable so that there is a `192.168.3.0/24` network, the peer-to-peer queries over `192.168.1.0/24` are resolved successfully. Without the `192.168.3.0/24` network, the peer-to-peer communication is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question 'Is there a fix (for my router swallowing local traffic)?' is no, because it is not happening.

The longer answer is when a host sends traffic to another host it will calculate whether the host is on the same subnet (by using the destination address and its own mask) and, if it is, it will send out an arp request for that local host's MAC address, the router does not get involved.

How are you connecting the PCs with the patch cable? Do they have secondary NICs?

I suspect that the reason it is working with the patch cable is because there is some sort of firewall on one of the PCs (not necessarily the target) that is configured for the 192.168.1.0/24 interface but not the new interface you are setting up.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It was the Win7 PC that was ruining the connection, because the network was set as "Public". Can anyone explain why it was happening? I had firewalls configured and everything. I thought it should be possible to get some apps outside of public zone.